# How can I detect all the pages in a redirect with php?

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

i found this question on quora and didn't know how to resolve it

Scenario --

User is on one.php and clicks a link that points to two.php

Two.php does a header redirect to three.php

If we check the referring URL on three.php $_SERVER shows one.php instead of two.php

How do we find out that two.php was an intermediate page that did a header redirect?

Note that I can not do anything with one.php or two.php that can include any params saying two.php included in the redirect

Comment: What's the URL of the question on quora?

Comment: http://www.quora.com/PHP/How-can-I-detect-all-the-pages-in-a-redirect-with-php/answer/Mark-Mutti?__snids__=43486043

Comment: @user1125516 You have no access to the .php files, or any common template file that they all share?

Comment: i guess he can't, may be the page one & two are third party

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Save the Record with Sessions

You can save the stack on a session variable. Just keep unshifting values onto `$_SESSION["history"]`, removing items from the end of the array when the collection grows to a certain size.

For instance:

```
// Need to do this if we wish to store data
session_start();

// Set the history array if it doesn't exist
isset( $_SESSION["history"] ) || $_SESSION["history"] = array();

// Push current URI onto history
array_unshift( $_SESSION["history"], $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );

// Prevent history from exceeding 5 values
array_splice( $_SESSION["history"], 5 );
```

#### Load it into all PHP files

This would need to be added to the top of each file, or to a global header template include if you have one. Alternatively, if you dare, you could load it globally using `auto_prepend_file`:

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require function, so include_path is used. - [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

#### Inspect the History

You could show the entire history by accessing `$_SESSION["history"]`:

```
// Output history array
var_dump( $_SESSION["history"] );
```

Comment: Make sure to serialize it first.

Comment: How does this work if he's not able to modify those php files?

Comment: @Aknosis The OP said they cannot include parameters. Not that they can't touch the files.

Comment: This basic technique is valuable, even considering the constraints.  You could potentially do this without modifying the scripts using something like `auto_prepend_file`

Comment: @JonathanSampson maybe I misread, I guess he's saying he can't change the location to be 3.php?prev=1.php right?

Comment: @Aknosis I believe that's what he's saying. He cannot redirect to `3.php?from=1.php`.

Comment: that's not the point, he just want to have a kind of history of redirects, say the client came from page2, so call to specific function1, if he came from anther page, call to default functionX, but as mentioned below by @Nick the browser is masking page2

Comment: @user1125516 So you only want to know the most recent referer?

Comment: i want to get the right referer, page two in the question scenario but the referer from $_SERVER is one, two is hidden by the browser apparently

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have access to one.php or two.php, there are no workarounds here. Since two.php provided a redirect, the browser passes the referrer along, masking two.php. This is not specified in the RFC but it is the convention in clients.

If you did have access, you could pass the referrer URL in the query while still using a 301. Adding a hash or signature could be used to validate the URL.

Comment: is it possible to have a kind of history of redirects in PHP ?

Comment: Sure. If you can use a cookie or a unique identifier, keeping an array populated with the request URIs would be trivial, see @JonathanSampson for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sessions or cookies. You would want to mark the entries with time, and only consider entries with very close timestamps.

Answer (score -1):

You could make use of GET parameters in the redirect from two.php to three.php.

So in two.php:

header('Location: three.php?source=two.php');

and then in three.php you check for $_GET['source'];

Comment: The OP specified that there should not be any parameters indicating that two.php is included in the redirect.